# Which Level is Better For Inspection in CRUD Operation?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, unit-of-work

I am using UnitOfWork pattern in my application. I implemented **Remove** method in Page like bellow:

```
public IActionResult OnPostRemove(int id)
{
    var report = db.tblDailyReportPiping.Find(id);

    if (report == null)
        return new JsonResult(new { status = false, message = "Invalid Data" });

    //Only user whci created data can remove data
    if (report.fldUserId != HttpContext.Session.GetActiveUser_UserId())
        return new JsonResult(new { status = false, message = "Incorrect user" });

    //current row shal no be approved or finalized
    if (report.fldApproved || report.fldFinalized)
        return new JsonResult(new { status = false, message = "Approved or finalized before" });

    try
    {
        //remove
        if (!db.tblDailyReportPiping.Remove(report))
            return new JsonResult(new { status = false, message = "unable to remove" });

        //save
        if (db.SaveChangesByUserId(HttpContext.Session.GetActiveUser_UserId()) == 0)
            return new JsonResult(new { status = false, message = "unable to save" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new JsonResult(new { status = false, message = ex.Message });
    }

    return new JsonResult(true);
}
```

Before using **Remove** method from UOW, I inspected situation like **userId** and other **situation**. My question is: In which level I must inspect situation before CRUD operation? Both is possible, less code in action control or in repository but, which one is best practice?

I may use **Remove** from repository from different part of my application and by moving all code to repository I can lessen code line throughout in my application and just use **Remove** method from repository but, I must pass some extra parameter to method like userId, is it correct approach?

Thank you all

Comment: *"I am using UnitOfWork pattern in my application"*. Don't. You are specifically not supposed to when using EF because EF already does so. The `DbContext` IS a unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository. If you add extra layers yourself then you are just creating complexity and problems. Your service layer should work directly with the `DbContext`.

Comment: Thank you user18387401. But I don't want to repeat all code to check situation before calling remove method. How can I do that by DbSet directly? I want just use Remove with parameter and not to think about details in all part of my application. is there a way to do that?

Comment: I am worry about many refer to database. As I use same **DbContext** and use **Find** method at first line, is it correct to check **userId** in my controller and move all other inspection code to repository layer? Dose it make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action methods should be tiny and usually consist of max 3 lines. To do that create a new `DailyReportPipingService` and then move all of the `OnPostRemove` method's code to a new method there called `public Result RemoveReport(int userId)`. Now use this new method in your action method. The `Result` will have a `T Result` property and a `bool Success` and `string? ErrorMessage` properties. Your validation logic is fine and can be extracted/refactored to a new method in that service to use it in other methods as well. If you don't like this type of validation, you can also create a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` for it and do your validation and if there's an error, add it to the `ModelState.AddModelError()` of the ActionFilter. This is how the AOP/Aspect oriented programming is implemented in the MVC using `ActionFilter`s. Also you can change the `int id` parameter of the `OnPostRemove` method to a class and write a custom validator for it. Usually the validation is a `cross-cutting concern` and shouldn't be mixed with your `business logic`. So writing a custom validator for the action method's parameter is a better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you dear `VahidN`.

Sorry if my problem is beginner.

My solution consist of `IRepositories` project (interface classes) and `Repository` project (Implementation of IRepositories):

1. Am I need to add more project to my solution? Or should I refactor current structure?
2. I need some data from client to check criteria before any action, can I pass more parameter to repository method from action methods or any front (WPF, WinApp)?
3. In some scenario I want to force method to remove data whiteout any criteria because current user is `Admin`. For this I added `bool force` parameter to method. If the value is `true`, remove will be done immediately.
4. In most methods three parameters is important: 1) `id` 2) `userId` 3) `force`. Can I pass them to methods?
5. If I create `custome ActionFilter`, finally I need to get data and do my validation. so, why not do validation in `Remove` method? Mybe final application be a windows application or WPF in which, I do not have `ActionFilter` and I should create new validation method.

My biggest concern is some data which exist in `HttpContext` or `Session` of current user. In any kind of pattern which needs to create new and separate project (`for modularization`), I must pass these data to new project. And if I want to eliminate new project I must create new namespace in WebApp project to have access to `HttpContext` or `Session` data.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If my problem has ambiguity, please tell me to clarify that.

Comment: Is it correct to define several overloading for **Remove** and **Update** with different input parameter? Is it recommended?